# how can i add to rectangle with arrows border

Tags: css, css-shapes

Hello I would ask how can i add a border in a rectangle with arrows that I made. My code is:

```css
a.trapez_sharp::after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #ED1D24!important;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 0;
}
a.trapez_sharp {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 44px;
    background: #ED1D24;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 6px 0 8px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 29px 0 17px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
a.trapez_sharp::before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #ED1D24;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<a class="trapez_sharp" href="www.google.gr">See our services -></a>
```

I want to add a border line that will display the shape.I can add on the a.trapez_sharp  the  border: 1px solid #ffffff; ,but  when I go to add it to the after and before it is ruined.
Any suggestion will help